# How to retrieve nth element from the sorted keys of sorted TreeMap?

Tags: html-lists, treemap, treeset

I am using `TreeMap` to as I want to store sorted keys. I have also passed the comparator to sort the order. Now, I want to retrieve the 2nd key form the map. How do I go about doing it.  The `TreeMap` is as given below :

```
private TreeMap<Coupon, LineItem> couponVsDiscountLine = new TreeMap<>((c1, c2) -> c1.weight().compareTo(c2.weight()));
```

Getting the sorted keys from `TreeMap` :

```
TreeSet<Coupon> coupons = (TreeSet<Coupon>) couponVsDiscountLine.keySet();
```

There is no method in `TreeSet` to get(index) as the elements in `TreeSet` are not indexed.

Other question, which `Set` does `keySet()` method of `TreeMap` return? How does `TreeMap` store the keys internally?

I read in some post that the `TreeMap` or `TreeSet` does not maintain the order if any modifications is done on that. Does it mean that retrieval of element may not give the elements in the order specified in the comparator?

Comment: I have created the List of TreeSet using the code "ArrayList<Coupon> coupons = new ArrayList<>(couponVsDiscountLine.keySet());". Now I can retrieve 2nd element by coupons.get(2). Still, not sure if it the way to go? Any other suggestions?